# False Convergence for Fat-tail distribution fitting

Tags: r

I am sharing a problem regarding distribution fitting of stock return in R. 
I am fitting skewed generalized error distribution SGED in R through fGarch package. but the problem is it gives a false convergence. Can anyone guide me how to correct this false convergence. I am sharing output below.

```
sgedFit(R1)
$par
     mean        sd        nu        xi 
0.0900983 1.4345571 0.7090691 1.0506317 

$objective
[1] 5054.761

$convergence
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 26

$evaluations
function gradient 
      59      153 

$message
[1] "false convergence (8)"
```

please guide me how to correct this false convergence because with this message I don't have valid estimated parameters

Comment: Provide better starting values than the default?

Comment: Since this is a stats problem, [stats.se] might be better able to help. You're still going to have to post more information on your problem, ideally a [mcve] that reproduces the error